# Добавить свойство в панель свойств Delphi

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте.

Например, просто к TImage нужно добавить еще какое-нибудь свойство, чтоб можно было редактировать в панели свойств.

Я описываю свойство в Published, пишу read И write, но ничего не появляется. Прочитал, что нужно зарегистрировать как-то, но не могу понять как. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создать проект пакета. `File` -> `New` -> `Package Delphi`. Добавить в него юнит с вашим новым классом `TMyImage`. Скомпилить, а затем сделать `Install`.

```
unit MyImage;

interface

uses
  Classes, ExtCtrls;

type
  TMyImage = class(TImage)
  // новые свойства вашего класса
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Название вкладки с компонентами', [TMyImage]);
end;
```